# Excel VBA: Checking if range contains a cell with a specific color

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following two user defined functions:

```
Function GetFillColor(Rng As Range) As Long
    GetFillColor = Rng.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

and

```
Function ContainsColor(Rng As Range, Clr As Long) As Boolean
    ContainsColor = False
    For Each c In Rng
        If GetFillColor(c) = Clr Then
            ContainsColor = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

The second function does not seem to work when called like ContainsColor(A1:A5,35), what am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Try calling like `ContainsColor("A1:A5",35)` or `ContainsColor "A1:A5",35`

Comment: Try adding `Dim c As Range` , before your `For Each c In Rng`. You are using it as a **UDF** ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#NAME? error in Excel for VBA Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830181/name-error-in-excel-for-vba-function)

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure why you have 2 `Functions`, you can just use one:

```
Function ContainsColor(Rng As Range, Clr As Long) As Boolean

    Dim c As Range
    ContainsColor = False
    For Each c In Rng
        If c.Interior.ColorIndex = Clr Then
            ContainsColor = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

Calling it from Excel (in this case will result True, as Cell A1 `Interior.ColorIndex` = 35) :

[image]