# Excel VBA - VLookup when cell color is set

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a "colorfunction" created here with the intent to run a VLookup if the current cell background color is set to vbRed or rgb(255,0,0). Right now the VLookup is looking for the SKU number from my worksheet which is offset 8 columns to the left of the current cell and looking through my second sheet "Order Guide" range A:AD to pull the corresponding data.

Currently it's only returning #NAME? even though I can manually validate both SKUs are in the
proper locations. My current function is written as:

```
Function ColorFunction(Rge As Range) As String

Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim SKUColumn As Range
Dim MyRange as Range

Set Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Order Guide")
Set SKUColumn = Rge.Offset(0, -8)
Set MyRange = Sheet.Range("A:AD")

If Application.ThisCell.Interior.Color = vbRed Then ColorFunction = 
Application.ThisWorkbook.VLookup(SKUColumn, MyRange, 30, False)

End Function
```

[Module Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hFWt.jpg)

Not entierly sure what I'm missing here...

Comment: where did you put this function.  Is it in a common module or in the worksheet module.  It should be in the prior.

Comment: As was alluded to in a comment to your [now deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70336350/vba-vlookup-if-cell-color-is-red).

Comment: Function is in a common module @ScottCraner

Comment: @BigBen Is this not where the function is supposed to be stored?

Comment: That looks right, next check any of the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830181/name-error-in-excel-for-vba-function

Comment: And that module is attached to the workbook in which you are trying to use it?

Comment: Correct @ScottCraner

Comment: Can you also paste the formula that you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Workbook has no `VLookup`-method.

Either use

```
ColorFunction = Application.Vlookup(SKUColumn, MyRange, 30, False)
```

This will return the common #N/A if VLookup cannot find the value.

or use

```
ColorFunction = "(not found)"
On Error Resume Next
ColorFunction = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SKUColumn, MyRange, 30, False)
On Error Goto 0
```

The `WorksheetFunction` will throw a runtime error. If you don't handle that error, you will get a `#VALUE`-error in the cell if the value is not found. In my example, I return  `"(not found)"` instead.

**Update** (*Sigh*, havn't read the deleted question, I guess we are not supposed to do so)
The `#Name`-Error occurs if Excel cannot find the VBA function. Can be caused by

- Function is not public
- Function is not in a regular module
- Module is not in the current workbook or a referenced workbook
- Name of Module and Name of Function is identical

(If anyone knows another reason, feel free to add...)

Comment: Of course OP had it correct in the [previous version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70336350/vba-vlookup-if-cell-color-is-red). Though this doesn't explain a `#NAME?` result.

Comment: Right, I tried this in the last post as @BigBen suggested. Similarly to now, it still throws a #NAME? result.

Comment: @cgwoz what is the exact formula you are using: `=ColorFunction(...)`? What do you have as the argument?

Comment: I just tried your second solution Thomas and it seemed to work. @BigBen exact formula I have been trying was `=ColorFunction(J11)`. I'm not quite understanding why it was throwing a #NAME? result prior to this though...