VBA recognizes UDF when called in subfunction, but not when typed in Excel cell
I have coded a public function (z_samp(baseline as Double, prop_diff as Double) as Double) in the VBA window. When I call the function via a sub, everything works as expected. However, when I type "=z_samp(20,10)" into a cell, I get a #VALUE? error.
I have checked the Trust center settings (macros are enabled and the file is saved as .xlsm). I have also checked to make sure that the module I have written my UDF in is in the right place (I right clicked on VBAProject in the Project panel, and clicked Insert > new module.
I am not sure why excel is not recognizing my function in the sheet, but it is recognizing it when I call it via a subfunction. Any insight into what is causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

have you tried inserting it throught the function button? (fx on the entry bar, followed by user defined functions)?

What's the name of the module it is in (it should not be the same as the function name), and is it in the same workbook that you are trying to use it in?

do you have the function defined multiple times in the workbook?

Scroll through thos post for possible solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830181/name-error-in-excel-for-vba-function

@Rory the name of the module is Module2 and yes, I think it is in the same workbook. In the project panel, I can see VBAProject > Modules > Module2

@twegner No, but that was a good check thank you

@Paul I have tried typing "z_samp(20,10) into the fx bar, but still receive the #NAME? error. Is this what you were suggesting I try? I'm assuming your reference to user defined functions is where I was supposed to type "z_samp(20,10)" (i.e.: the name of my UDF)

Workbook_Open() belongs in the ThisWorkbook module, so it can't be "above" your function definition.

UDFs can't generally write a value to another cell. There are workarounds, but generally things like calc_sheet.Range("$O$10").Value = baseline or calc_sheet.Range("$O$11").Value = baseline * (1 + prop_diff) will fail if the UDF is called from a cell.

@BigBen Thank you for the tip. What are some of these workarounds/can you point me in the right direction?

The workaround is to use a sub, IMO, but if you're set on the UDF route, see this.

@BigBen - I've tried using a sub, but the problem is that it requires the parameters to z_samp(baseline, prop_diff) to be hard-coded. I updated the code in my issue box to help show what I mean

You could for example input those parameters in worksheet cells, then read the values when calling the sub.

No, I didn't mean typing it in, but clicking on fx and selecting user defined, then clicking on the function name when it appears. That way, you will see the function even if it is in another open workbook.
