Function in excel contains unrecognized text from a code I made in microsoft VBA
I used a function in visual basic for applications and it worked previously but not anymore (first time I did this in excel). Here is the code:
Function CheckForFloodInRange(rng As Range) As Integer
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim found As Boolean
    found = False
    
    For Each cell In rng
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, "flood", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell
    
    If found Then
        CheckForFloodInRange = 1
    Else
        CheckForFloodInRange = 0
    End If
End Function

The code is supposed to filter texts on the word 'flood' over several columns, but it gives the error instead:

And this is what the VBA loos like:

In the end I would also like to be able to save the code to this specific excel file, but for now it would be great if I can apply the function again. Let me know if anything is unclear. Thanks!

What Excel version are you working with. Usually the file has to be saved as an *.xlsm file to have VBA code. Furthermore it would help to see how the formula in T1 looks like.

Do you call this function from a cell? Do you only need to check if in the respective range the searched string exists?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18830358 from the linked thread.

#NAME indicates that Excel cannot find the function.
There might be different reasons for that (function is Private, typo in the name), but in your case it's a different reason: You cannot call a function as UDF that is defined in a worksheet or workbook module.
Simply create a new standard module (according to your screenshot, you don't have one yet) and put the function into that module.

Your function takes a range as a parameter. Look at your formula and make sure that it is something like =CheckForFloodInRange($A2:$S2)
... where A is the first column to search, and S is the last. 2 is the row number and if you duplicate that cell, it should increment.
Please include your formula in your question if you need further help.

An invalid parameter would result in a #VALUE error. A #NAME error happens when Excel cannot find the function at all - in this case because it's not stored in a standard module
